# The range of constant $k$ for which all the roots of equation $x^4+4x^3-8x^2\:+k\:=0$ are real.

Tags: roots

The range of constant $k$ for which all the roots of equation $x^4+4x^3-8x^2\:+k\:=0$ are real.

Options

a) $(1,3)$
b) $[1,3]$
c) $(-1,3)$
d) $(-1,3] $

Comment: So what have you tried to do yourself?

Comment: I have no clue in this question. I used hit and trial method and tried to solve the equations by putting k = -1,1,3.

Comment: Compute $\Delta$ for the quartic equation.

Answer (score 1):

None of them. The correct answer must be $k\in (0,3)$.

For the graph to cross the $x$-line four times, two local mins must be below it and one local max must be above it.

We will find the critical points of $f(x)=x^4+4x^3-8x^2+k$:
$$\begin{align}f'(x)&=4x^3+12x^2-16x=0 \Rightarrow x_{1,2,3}=-4,0,1\\
min:&f(-4)=-128+k<0 \Rightarrow k<128\\
max:&f(0)=k>0\\
min:&f(1)=-3+k<0 \Rightarrow k<3\end{align}$$ 
See Desmos [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pzabjglmoa).

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)\equiv x^4+4x^3-8x^2\:+k\:=0$$

If this four degree polynomial has four real roots, then there is a local minimum between the first two and between the last two roots, and a local maximum between the second and third root.

The location of the extrema does not change with $k$, only their $y$-values.
Thus we are looking for $k$ such that the two local minima have negative $y$-values and the local maximum has positive $y$-value.

Locate the local extrema as roots of the derivative
$$ 4x^3+12x^2-16x = 4x(x^2+3x-4)=4(x+4)x(x-1),$$
i.e. the minima are at $x=-4$ and $x=1$, the maximum is at $x=0$.

The respective values of $f(x)$ are $f(-4)=-128+k$, $\quad y(0)=k \quad $, and $y(1)=-3+k$. We conclude that the desired condition is
$$ 0<k<3\qquad \text{and}\qquad k<128$$

Comment: Thank you brother

Comment: Can $k<128$ be dropped?

Comment: I think so. Try it.